# Restful MessageBodyWriter not found

Tags: java, json, rest, glassfish, media-type

I am working on Restful service. The problem occurred after we moved to Glassfish 4.1 . The error string is :

**SEVERE:   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=...**

But my classes consume application/json. Here is example:

```
@Path("get_customer_info")
@Consumes("application/json;charset=utf8")
public class CustomerInfoResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public CustomerInfoResource () {
    }

    @POST
    public Player getPlayerInfo(){
    ....
    }
}
```

I have done the following and could not solve it:
Added all jersey jars version 2.13 , jackson jars 2.4.3 . Also added jersey-media-json-jackson-2.13.jar which contains org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature class. By the way ApplicationConfig class is:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("resources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        try {
            Class jsonProvider = Class.forName("org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature");
            resources.add(jsonProvider);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding the @Produces annotation at the class level. It seems the problem is occurring while writing the response.

Comment: Of course tried @Produces but it does not solved also. Actually the project was working in Glassfish 4.0 . The problem occurs only in Glassfish 4.1 .

Comment: I think the reason is that by default your post method produces XML, and your `Player` class is not serializable. If you want to get around this easily, and you don't mind returning Json, you could use something like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and then do something like this: `BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mention @Consumes("application/json") at your MessageBodyReader implementation. I have already written some custom MessageBodyWriter with @Produces. It is working fine for me. I hope this will also work for you in the case of MessageBodyReader

Refer: http://h2labz.blogspot.in/2014/12/marshalling-java-to-json-in-jax-rs.html